# Button with spinner get cut in half

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I have a table where inside a column, I have a button. When pushing that button, I activate the spinner "loading state". I keep that state in memory, so if I move around to other pages and come back, I can get the state and apply it to that button

The spinner and the look of the button are ok when I start the spinner, but if I change page and comes back, the button still has the spinner, but it is cut in half

Before

[image]

After

[image]

The html looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="left">Name</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">The item name</td>
      <td>
        <button [clrLoading]="stoppingState" type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-outline" (click)="stopBroadcasting()">
          <clr-icon shape="stop"></clr-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey David. It seems like there is something going on. Can you recreate this issue in a minimal StackBlitz? Here is a link to the Clarity issue starter: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v012

Comment: Hi @hippeelee. Here is the link: https://clarity-light-theme-v012-wlfkk1.stackblitz.io . Not too sure how to share the code at the same time. If you could guide me, it would be nice.

Comment: Go to Page1, push the button. Then go to the Home page. The button will be cut and if you go back to Page1, same thing. Any reason why the icon is wrong? It should be a square!

Comment: Here the link with the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v012-wlfkk1

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is whats happening. In your example, when you set the value for the `ClrLoadingButton` state the view for the loading button is not fully initialized and the icon for the spinner is not in the DOM. There is a method, `ClrLoadingButton.setExplicitButtonWidth`, that runs when loading state is changed and it calculates the button width. Since the loading spinner isn't in the DOM at that time it calculates the wrong width.

I moved the code that accesses your service and sets the `stoppingState` into `ngAfterViewInit` and it works as I would expect.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.stoppingState = this.myService.getStopState();
}
```

Here is a link to the modified StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v012-3xmqmh

Comment: Make perfectly sense! Thanks @hippeelee.